# Convert a double to fixed decimal point in C++

Tags: c++, decimal, fixed-point

I have a double variable in C++ and want to print it out to the screen as a fixed decimal point number.

Basically I want to know how to write a function that takes a double and a number of decimal places and prints out the number to that number of decimal places, zero padding if necessary.

For example:

```
convert(1.235, 2)
```

would print out

```
1.24
```

and

```
 convert(1, 3)
```

would print out

```
1.000
```

so the function works as

```
convert(number as double, number of decimal places)
```

and simply prints out the required value to standard output (cout).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I'm remembering my format strings correctly,

```
printf("%.*f", (int)precision, (double)number);
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [setprecision manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) which should give you the idea

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "fixed decimal place" number. The convert function will need to be the function that actually prints it out. I would suggest getting the whole part of the number, then print it. If [decimal places]>0 then print a decimal place, then print each decimal individually like: `floor((n*log(10,d))%10);` <-- just an idea, not actual code.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream.h>

// print a float, x places of precision 
void convert (double number, int x)
{
    cout << setprecision(x) << number << endl;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 1.234;
    convert (a,2);
}
```

output: 1.23

[reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)