# print double with precision 4 using cout

Tags: c++, double, precision, cout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a double to fixed decimal point in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844010/convert-a-double-to-fixed-decimal-point-in-c)

Suppose  , I have `double a = 0`  and I want to print it as `0.0000`  .

I've tried this :

```
cout.precision(4) ; 
cout<<a<<endl ;
```

but it gaves `0` as the output.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't provide a direct answer to the question, the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just try:

```
#include <iomanip>
...
cout << fixed << setprecision(4);
cout << a << endl;
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream.h>


int main()
{
double a = 0.00;
// print a double, 2 places of precision 
cout << setprecision(4) << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Apart from missing `std::`s and non existent `iostream.h`, without `std::fixed` this simply doesn't work.

Comment: @Avio It works well with visual studio

Comment: @crh225 This shouldn't work and is not language consistent.