# Printing float and double values using cout in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

For the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Hall
{
 public:
 double cost;
};
int main()
{
 Hall hall;
 hall.cost=10000.50;
 cout<<hall.cost;
 return 0;
}
```

Why does this code output 10000.5 and not 10000.50, can someone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Hmm... I found other questions regarding [how to get the zero to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728425/print-double-with-precision-4-using-cout), but not one asking why. In other words, I found related questions, but not a duplicate.

Comment: *can someone explain the logic behind this?*  The code did not ask to print the trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

> can someone explain the logic behind this?

The default behaviour is not show any trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

`double` (and floating-point variables in general) don't store a specific spelling of the number (base-10 or otherwise). That would be way too inefficient, and the ability to store meaningless zeroes would waste memory.

Instead, the numbers are encoded [in a certain binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Printing them reproduces the base-10 spelling from binary.

Answer (score 1):

By default, C++ does not display trailing zeros, however the standard library `<iomanip>` can be used along with std::fixed from `<iostream>`. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
  double myVar = 123.4;
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2); // 2 trailing digits
  std::cout << myVar << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```