# How to slice (c++)

Tags: c++

I am learning basic c++, and I am confused on how to slice. For example, if a = 2.43231, how do I make it output only 2.43?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
float a = 2.4323 ;

cout << a;

};
```

Comment: `cout<<setprecision(2)<<a`

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a double to fixed decimal point in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844010/convert-a-double-to-fixed-decimal-point-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not slicing. It's just controlling the precision when you print out the number.

```cpp
    #include <iomanip>

    // ...
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << a;
```

Slicing is something completely different, involving inheritance and assigning a value of a derived class to an instance of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

The [printf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) function is really handy for situations like this, especially as your output strings become increasingly complicated with multiple variables. With `printf`, your output line would look like this: `printf("%.2f", a)`.

If you want to use `cout`, see Jerry Coffin's answer.